# Parsing a Multi-Index Excel File in Pandas

Tags: python, excel, parsing, pandas, time-series

I have a time series excel file with a tri-level column MultiIndex that I would like to successfully parse if possible.  There are some results on how to do this for an index on stack overflow but not the columns and the `parse` function has a `header` that does not seem to take a list of rows.

The ExcelFile looks like is like the following:

- Column A is all the time series dates starting on A4
- Column B has top_level1 (B1) mid_level1 (B2) low_level1 (B3) data (B4-B100+)
- Column C has null (C1) null (C2) low_level2 (C3) data (C4-C100+)
- Column D has null (D1) mid_level2 (D2) low_level1 (D3) data (D4-D100+)
- Column E has null (E1) null (E2) low_level2 (E3) data (E4-E100+)
- ...

So there are two `low_level` values many `mid_level` values and a few `top_level` values but the trick is the top and mid level values are null and are assumed to be the values to the left.  So, for instance all the columns above would have top_level1 as the top multi-index value.

My best idea so far is to use `transpose`, but the it fills `Unnamed: #` everywhere and doesn't seem to work.  In Pandas 0.13 `read_csv` seems to have a `header` parameter that can take a list, but this doesn't seem to work with `parse`.

Comment: It would be useful to have a comment or two from the down voters so i know how to phrase the question differently next time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can `fillna` the null values. I don't have your file, but you can test

```
#Headers as rows for now
df = pd.read_excel(xls_file,0, header=None, index_col=0) 

#fill in Null values in "Headers"
df = df.fillna(method='ffill', axis=1) 

#create multiindex column names
df.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df[:3].values, names=['top','mid','low']) 

#Just name of index
df.index.name='Date' 

#remove 3 rows which are already used as column names
df = df[pd.notnull(df.index)]
```

Comment: Thanks.  `header=None` was what I was missing here as this avoids the multiple `Unnamed` column names allowing the horizontal fill.  Well done.